What is the effective dimension of subspace when global unitary is restricted?
Consider any three-qubit state $\vert \psi \rangle \in \mathcal{H}^{\otimes 3}$, and let $U$ be a global unitary that can act on the whole state $\vert \psi \rangle$. Then, it is obvious that the "dimension" of the subspace given by the set $\{U\vert \psi \rangle \}$ is $\mathrm{dim}(\mathcal{H}^{\otimes 3}) = 8$ as there always exists $U$ that can take $\vert \psi \rangle$ to any other state in $\mathcal{H}^{\otimes 3}$.
Now, say that the unitary $U$ takes the form $\mathcal{I} \otimes U_2 \otimes \mathcal{I}$, where $U_2$ is a single qubit unitary, then it is clear that the set $\{ (\mathcal{I} \otimes U_2 \otimes \mathcal{I})\vert \psi \rangle \}$ is a smaller set, and hence would correspond to a smaller subspace (less than a dimension of 8). This, of course, depends on what state $\vert \psi \rangle$ we begin with.
Is there any way to approach this problem? Here's what I tried:

Parameterise the single qubit unitary and, for a given $\vert \psi \rangle$, explicitly calculate the output $(\mathcal{I} \otimes U_2 \otimes \mathcal{I})\vert \psi \rangle$. What we have now is a parameterized vector; each entry can be thought of as a function. I calculate its Jacobian and then find its rank. Few Math StackExchange answers tell me that the dimension of the image of a function (function here is the one that takes a vector of input parameters to the state $(\mathcal{I} \otimes U_2 \otimes \mathcal{I})\vert \psi \rangle$) is equal to the rank of the Jacobian. The problem is that I haven't taken a course on differential manifolds to confirm if this is true.

I could try calculating the number of free real parameters here, which is 3 (for unitary  $U_2$). The thing is, if I use this argument for the case of $U\vert \psi \rangle$, $U$ has $2^{2*3}-1 = 63$ parameters, so this argument that a number of free parameters is the dimension of the subspace is plain wrong here.


Is there any explicit way to approach such a problem in general?

Well if a person gives you a diagonalizable matrix and anything more, be educated and diagonalize it!
First case, the global unitary $U$. If you diagonalize it you can write
$$
U = \sum_{i=1}^8 e^{i\theta_i}|\theta_i\rangle\!\langle \theta_i|
$$
So we have
$$
U|\Psi\rangle= \sum_{i=1}^8 e^{i\theta_i}\langle \theta_i|\Psi\rangle|
\theta_i\rangle
$$
which is a span of $8$ vectors, so it dimension is 8. By applying the same reasoning for the two quit unitary
$$
I\otimes U_2\otimes = e^{i\theta_1}I\otimes |\theta_1\rangle\!\langle \theta_1 \otimes I +\\+ e^{i\theta_2}I\otimes |\theta_2\rangle\!\langle \theta_2| \otimes I
$$
By applying it in the state, we have a span of two states, so a space of dimension 2. This is the meaning of eigenvectors and eigenvalues: the number of non null eigenvalues are exactly the dimension of the image space of a matrix and it eigenvectors span it.
